# From UIView to UIImage ( LottieAnimation)

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, uiimage

I have lottieAnimation on my cell, using slider i can change the current frame of the animation, next what i want is to save my animation on scpecific frame as UIImage, so i can save it to users library. Using lottieAnimation method .snapShotView, i got UIView of animation on frame that i want, the problem is when i am trying to convert this UIView to UIImage i am getting blank white Image( how can i fix it? thanks!

here is my code:

```
func saveCurrentShotFrame() {
    guard let shotFrameImage = animationView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)?.asImage() else { return }
    
    delegate?.cellDidSaveShotFrameImage(shotFrameImage)
}
```

extension:

extension UIView {

```
func asImage() -> UIImage {
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
    return renderer.image { rendererContext in
        layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to add dispatch async before took the screenshot

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async { 
      guard let shotFrameImage = animationView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)?.asImage() else { return }
    
      delegate?.cellDidSaveShotFrameImage(shotFrameImage)
}
```